# Google Charts API custom month names

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to set custom month names in Charts.

How set custom month names in Google Charts API?

Comment: which chart are you using? are the names part of the data or axis labels? need more to go on, example would be great.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/s0w4oht1/1/ I need custom names for "Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun ...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify custom `ticks` on the `hAxis`...

```js
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Rating');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

        data.addRows([
          [new Date(2015, 1, 1), 5, 'January'],
          [new Date(2015, 2, 1), 7, 'February'],
          [new Date(2015, 3, 1), 3, 'March'],
          [new Date(2015, 4, 1), 2, 'April'],
          [new Date(2015, 5, 1), 2, 'May']
        ]);


        var options = {
          width: 900,
          height: 500,
          hAxis: {
            format: 'MMM',
            gridlines: {count: 5},
            ticks: [
              {v: new Date(2015, 1, 1), f:'custom 1'},
              {v: new Date(2015, 2, 1), f:'custom 2'},
              {v: new Date(2015, 3, 1), f:'custom 3'},
              {v: new Date(2015, 4, 1), f:'custom 4'},
              {v: new Date(2015, 5, 1), f:'custom 5'}
            ]
          },
          vAxis: {
            gridlines: {color: 'none'},
            minValue: 0
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: good, but if mouse over point on chars, showing tooltips with standart month name